# Convert Mat to bitmap on cameraview

Tags: android, opencv, bitmap, mat

I want to convert `private Mat  mRgba;`to `private Bitmap bmp;`then crop the image to put in imageview on camera view, it's no error and it can run on my device but it's not showing right 
, doesn't change the image, here is my code

```
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Log.i(TAG, "called onCreate");
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);

    setContentView(R.layout.tutorial1_surface_view);

    if (mIsJavaCamera)
        mOpenCvCameraView = (CameraBridgeViewBase) findViewById(R.id.tutorial1_activity_java_surface_view);
    mOpenCvCameraView.setVisibility(SurfaceView.VISIBLE);
    mOpenCvCameraView.setCvCameraViewListener(this);
}
    public Mat onCameraFrame(CvCameraViewFrame inputFrame) {
    mRgba = inputFrame.rgba();
    mGray = inputFrame.gray();      
    return mRgba;
}
    public void onCameraViewStarted(int width, int height) {
    mGray = new Mat();
    mRgba = new Mat(height, width, CvType.CV_8UC4);

    @Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        Mat tmp = new Mat (480, 800, CvType.CV_8U, new Scalar(4));
        try {
            //Imgproc.cvtColor(seedsImage, tmp, Imgproc.COLOR_RGB2BGRA);
            Imgproc.cvtColor(mRgba, tmp, Imgproc.COLOR_RGBA2BGRA, 4);
            bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(tmp.cols(), tmp.rows(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
            Utils.matToBitmap(tmp, bmp);                
            ImageView Img = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);               
            Img.setImageBitmap(bmp);


        }
        catch (Exception e){Log.d("Exception",e.getMessage());}
    }

    return false;
}
```

Thanks for the help

Comment: I think I solve the problem , I just upgrad the all SDK Tool and ADT.
but got the another problem, the image size is full screen and color become very strange ...